# Python: items not being removed from list

Tags: python, list, mode

```
listsal2 = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8]
listsal3 = []

counter = 0
for i in listsal2:
    item = listsal2.count(i)

    if item > 1:
        counter = item 
        while counter > 1:
            listsal3.append(i)   
            counter = counter - 1




print (listsal3)
```

I've been working on a mode function but for some reason it keeps the last couple numbers in the list and the more items in the list, the more that don't get removed.

EDIT: just realized I forgot the 2nd part of the code which is now in

EDIT2: code is shrunken down and easier to read

EDIT3: changed code so the duplicate numbers go into a new list but it has the multiple amounts of the list item

Thanks to all for the help I think I've got it now

Comment: `a = a` - what were you expecting that to do?

Comment: Debug your code, and you'll immediately find the problem.

Comment: `if a > b` - you set `a` to `0` and `b` to a nonnegative number. How could `a` possibly be greater than `b`?

Comment: @user2357112 the reason a = a is because sometimes the list will not be organized so a might be larger than the new b value

Comment: `a = a` doesn't do anything.  "Assign the name a to the object named a".  Just remove it.

Comment: Assigning meaningful names instead of a/b/c would go a long way to making the code understandable.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I changed the a into a better name

Comment: Removing elements of a list while iterating over the list breaks the iteration.  Do not modify the `listsal2` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Your original program reminds me of some compiler course homework. I think you probably mean `listsal2.remove(i)` instead of `listsal2.remove(item)`.

Comment: @Cyker I kinda have that now except its now in a new list

Comment: If you aren't removing items, then what is the problem now?

Comment: @Antimony I still have to figure out how to get the most occurring number into the new list and how to properly remove them from the new so I don't have duplicates as I currently have it going into a new list if it occurs more than once not if it occurs the most.

Comment: If you want to look at only the unique items in your original list, then convert it to a set like this: `newset = set(listsal2)`, then convert it back to a list like this: `newlist = list(newset)` and iterate over those items.

Comment: @Antimony I first need to find the most occurring number(s) though then I need to do that in the new list but thanks for letting me know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, even after you account for `i=2` once, you go through the list again for 2, since it exists multiple times. This is why 2 and 3 end up in `listsal3` twice. Instead, what you want to do is only go through the list once for each unique item.

```
listsal2 = [1,2,2,3,3, 4]
newlist = set(listsal2)
listsal3 = []

counter = 0
for i in newlist:
    item = listsal2.count(i)

    if item > 1:
        counter = item 
        print counter
        while counter > 1:
            listsal3.append(i)   
            counter = counter - 1

print listsal2, listsal3
```

To get the unique items from your list, convert it to a set.

Another way to do it:
Simply keep a list containing the counts of each unique element, take the maximum of it, and trace back to the element that it corresponds to.

```
newset = set(listsal2)
newlist = list(set)
counts = []

for item in newlist:
    counts.append(listsal2.count(item))
maxcount = max(counts)
max_occurring_item = newlist[counts.index(maxcount)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are modifying the list while iterating it. This is in general not recommended because it breaks the iteration.

If you are going to remove all single and duplicate elements, the following code will do:

```
l = listsal2
l = [v for i, v in enumerate(l) if l.count(v) > 1 and l.index(v) == i]
```

This preserves the order in the original list.